Provider type mismatch Terraform
This is the configuration in my provider.tf file
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }

    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "3.0.2"
    }
  }
}


# Configuration for Docker
provider "docker" {
  alias = "kreuzwerker"
  registry_auth {
    address  = local.aws_ecr_url 
    username = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.user_name
    password = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password
  }
  
}

After terraform init. I got an error message to reference in the module which I did here.
module "docker" {
    source            = "../childmodules/docker"
    providers  = {
        docker       = docker.kreuzwerker
    }
    region            = var.region
}

I got this error message instea
Error: Provider type mismatch
│ 
│   on main.tf line 41, in module "docker":
│   41:         docker       = docker.kreuzwerker
│ 
│ The local name "docker.kreuzwerker" in the root module represents provider "kreuzwerker/docker", but "docker" in module.docker represents "hashicorp/docker".
│ 
│ Each provider has its own distinct configuration schema and provider types, so this module's "docker" can be assigned only a configuration for hashicorp/docker, which is not required
│ by module.docker.
╵

d

You need to show the provider configuration inside the ../childmodules/docker source code. If you declared a docker provider in there, without including source = "kreuzwerker/docker" then Terraform is always going to default to the Hashicorp Docker provider, which is what is causing your error.
